# laravel interface class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have created an interface and so far tested the functions in the model and the interface.

I've now tried to apply it in my controller and initially came up with an error of: `Class golfmanager\service\creator\TicketCreatorInterface does not exist`

I have carried out a number of composer updates and composer dump-autoload but no change so far.

I added an entry to composer.json to autoload the class as follows:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/helpers",
        "app/golfmanager"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "golfmanager": "app/"
    }
},
```

[updated with corrections]

My controller class which is creating the error looks like this:

```
use golfmanager\service\creator\TicketCreatorInterface;

 //controller manages the ticket books

class BooksController extends BaseController {

/**
 * Book Repository
 *
 * @var Book
 */
protected $book;
protected $ticket;

public function __construct(Book $book, TicketCreatorInterface $ticket)
{
    $this->book = $book;
    $this->ticket = $ticket;
}
}
```

My interface is:

```
namespace golfmanager\service\creator;
//ticket creator interface

interface TicketCreatorInterface {

public function createTicket($input, $book);

 }
```

Pulling my hair out over this -

Doing a unit test throws up the error, when I try to view the page in the browser I simply get a blank page which never loads

I have a service provider set up as follows:

```
namespace golfmanager\service;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class GolfmanagerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(
        'app\golfmanager\service\creator\TicketCreatorInterface', 
        'app\golfmanager\service\creator\TicketCreator'
        ); 
}

}
```

I've missed something obvious just can't see it - where have I gone wrong?

[I've updated the methods above to the latest attempts]
Update:
In config/app.php I have the following under service providers:

```
//custom service providers
    'golfmanager\service\GolfmanagerServiceProvider'
```

and my test:

```
use Mockery as m;
use Way\Tests\Factory;

class BooksTest extends TestCase {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->mock = m::mock('Eloquent', 'Book');
    $this->collection = m::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection')->shouldDeferMissing();
}

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->attributes = Factory::book(['id' => 1]);
    $this->app->instance('Book', $this->mock);
}

public function tearDown()
{
    m::close();
}

public function testIndex()
{
    $this->mock->shouldReceive('all')->once()->andReturn($this->collection);
    $this->call('GET', 'books');

    $this->assertViewHas('books');
}
```

**Current Error:**

At the moment the error when I run the test is:

```
Cannot redeclare class TicketCreatorInterface in C:\wamp\www\golfmanager\golfmanager\app\golfmanager\service\creator\TicketCreatorInterface.php on line 5
```

When I run through the browser I get:

```
Class golfmanager\service\creator\TicketCreatorInterface does not exist
```

very confused - I don't know enought to resolve

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `psr-0` hash inside `autoload` in your `composer.json` file.

Like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/helpers",
        "app/golfmanager"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "golfmanager": "app/"
    }
},
```

And then `composer dump-autoload` again.

---

**Edit**

I've noticed that you are loading your `app/golfmanager` both in `classmap` and `psr-0`. Remove it from `classmap`, leaving only the `psr-0` entry, like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/helpers"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "golfmanager": "app/"
    }
},
```

Now, `composer dump-autoload` as usual, and you should get rid of the duplicated error.

Comment: Thank you. I've changed that but now get an error: `Cannot redeclare class TicketCreatorInterface in C:\wamp\www\golfmanager\golfmanager\app\golfmanager\service\creator\TicketCreatorInterface.php on line 5'  I've searched through my files and can't see anywhere else (that I understand) where this is being initiated. Confused!

Comment: I've tweaked with removing `app/golfmanager` from the autoload class map but then I get a fail on loading serviceprovider. When I run a unit test I get a cannot redeclare class TicketInterface' but then when I run the app in the browser I get an error: Class golfmanager\service\creator\TicketCreatorInterface does not exist.

Comment: tried removing the `use golfmanager\service\creator\TicketCreatorInterface` from books controller but then an error: `Target [TicketCreatorInterface] is not instantiable.`

Comment: tried adding namespace to serviceprovider, TicketCreatorInterface and TicketCreator which then creates a service provider not found error. Running around in circles here (wrestling jelly springs to mind!) (did a composer dump autoload on each of these

Comment: Ok-changed as to your edit composer dump-autoload - the error now is: 'Target [golfmanager\service\creator\TicketCreatorInterface] is not instantiable. So progress! Appreciate the help

Comment: That's because you need to bind your interface to your `TicketCreator` class. You can do that in your `ServiceProvider`

Comment: In my service provider I thought I had bound TicketCreator? Code as above - are the references correct?

Comment: That's happening when you run your test or in browser?

Comment: both running the test in phpunit and the app in the browser have the error ticketcreatorinterface is not instantiable. namespace errors?

Comment: Could be... You need 1) `composer.json` as I posted 2) `app.php` including your `ServiceProvider` 3) binding being done in your `ServiceProvider` 4) `composer dump-autoload` 5) no typos with namespaces/packages

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Manuel's answers and excellent help the final element that was wrong was in the namespace.

The interfaces existed in golfmanager\service\creator but I was trying to reference them in app\golfmanager\service\creator

so the binding is now:

```
class GolfmanagerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(
        'golfmanager\service\creator\TicketCreatorInterface', 
        'golfmanager\service\creator\TicketCreator'
        ); 
}

}
```